# How to pickle functions/classes defined in __main__ (python)

Tags: python, pickle

I would like to be able to pickle a function or class from within __main__, with the obvious problem (mentioned in other posts) that the pickled function/class is in the __main__ namespace and unpickling in another script/module will fail.

I have the following solution which works, is there a reason this should not be done?

The following is in myscript.py:

```
import myscript
import pickle

if __name__ == "__main__":               

    print pickle.dumps(myscript.myclass())

else:

    class myclass:
        pass
```

**edit**: The unpickling would be done in a script/module that *has access to* myscript.py and can do an `import myscript`.  The aim is to use a solution like [parallel python](http://www.parallelpython.com/) to call functions remotely, and be able to write a short, *standalone* script that contains the functions/classes that can be accessed remotely.

Comment: Doesn’t that structure defeat the purpose of combining a script and a module?  You could just make separate files.

Answer (score 5):

Pickle seems to look at the **main** scope for definitions of classes and functions. From inside the module you're unpickling from, try this:

```
import myscript
import __main__
__main__.myclass = myscript.myclass
#unpickle anywhere after this
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get a better handle on global objects by importing `__main__`, and using the methods available in that module.  This is what [dill](http://pythonhosted.org/dill) does in order to serialize almost anything in python. Basically, when dill serializes an interactively defined function, it uses some name mangling on `__main__` on both the serialization and deserialization side that makes `__main__` a valid module.

```
>>> import dill
>>> 
>>> def bar(x):
...   return foo(x) + x
... 
>>> def foo(x):
...   return x**2
... 
>>> bar(3)
12
>>> 
>>> _bar = dill.loads(dill.dumps(bar))
>>> _bar(3)
12
```

Actually, dill registers it's types into the `pickle` registry, so if you have some black box code that uses `pickle` and you can't really edit it, then just importing dill can magically make it work without monkeypatching the 3rd party code.

Or, if you want the whole interpreter session sent over as an "python image", dill can do that too.

```
>>> # continuing from above
>>> dill.dump_session('foobar.pkl')
>>>
>>> ^D
dude@sakurai>$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep 30 2013, 20:15:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5566)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill
>>> dill.load_session('foobar.pkl')
>>> _bar(3)
12
```

You can easily send the image across ssh to another computer, and start where you left off there as long as there's version compatibility of pickle and the usual caveats about python changing and things being installed.

I actually use dill to serialize objects and send them across parallel resources with [parallel python](http://www.parallelpython.com/), multiprocessing, and [mpi4py](https://bitbucket.org/mpi4py/mpi4py).  I roll these up conveniently into the [pathos](http://pythonhosted.org/pathos) package (and [pyina](http://pythonhosted.org/pyina) for MPI), which provides a uniform `map` interface for different parallel batch processing backends.

```
>>> # continued from above
>>> from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
>>> Pool(4).map(foo, range(10))
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
>>>
>>> from pyina.launchers import MpiPool
>>> MpiPool(4).map(foo, range(10))
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

There are also non-blocking and iterative maps as well as non-parallel pipe connections. I also have a pathos module for `pp`, however, it is somewhat unstable for functions defined in `__main__`. I'm working on improving that. If you like, fork [the code on github](https://www.github.com/uqfoundation) and help make the `pp` better for functions defined in `__main__`.  The reason `pp` doesn't pickle well is that `pp` does it's serialization tricks through using temporary file objects and reading the interpreter session's history... so it doesn't serialize objects in the same way that multiprocessing or mpi4py do.  I have a dill module `dill.source` that seamlessly does the same type of pickling that `pp` uses, but it's rather new.

Comment: But it doesn't seem to work if you load the dill object, or dill session, on a computer without access to the imported objects in the session or used in the saved object.

e.g.
```
from foo import bar
x = dict(bar=bar)
with open('test.pkl', 'wb') as fp:
       dill.dump(x, fp)
```
Then on a computer or session w/out access to your PYTHONPATH, if you do:
```
with open('test.pkl', 'rb') as fp:
      model = dill.load(fp)
# ^^ causes a "No module named foo" error
```

Comment: @HillarySanders: if you are trying to pickle a script that refers to a second local (i.e. uninstalled) module... then, yes -- that doesn't work unless you also transfer the non-installed module.

Comment: Mm, indeed. https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/123
Is the related issue #123 likely to be implemented at some point?

Comment: It would be really cool to see a library that e.g. took a python object (e.g. class instance) and recursively plucked up all of the dependencies, saved them, such that they could be loaded on another machine with no access to the original source code. This could even be combined w/ auto-generating a requirements.txt file. I feel like someone must have done this before, but I can't find an implementation online :).

Comment: @HillarySanders: that's the correct issue.  It's not that easy, and it's not been done before.  `dill` does much of what you are looking for (grabbing dependencies, etc), but specifically doesn't fetch a locally imported module.  It does get most dependencies in most cases, just not local modules.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to pickle something so that you can use it  somewhere else, separate from `test_script`, that's not going to work, because pickle (apparently) just tries to load the function from the module.  Here's an example:

test_script.py

```
def my_awesome_function(x, y, z):
    return x + y + z
```

picklescript.py

```
import pickle
import test_script
with open("awesome.pickle", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(test_script.my_awesome_function, f)
```

If you run `python picklescript.py`, then change the filename of `test_script`, when you try to load the function, it will fail. e.g.

Running this:

```
import pickle
with open("awesome.pickle", "rb") as f:
    pickle.load(f)
```

Will give you the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "load_pickle.py", line 3, in <module>
    pickle.load(f)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1090, in load_global
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1124, in find_class
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named test_script
```

Comment: I agree.  However, I am looking for a solution where the module/script has access to test_script.py, see my recent edit.