# in a pickle: how to serialise legacy objects for submission to a Python multiprocessing pool

Tags: object, multiprocessing, pickle, legacy

I have written a nice parallel job processor that accepts jobs (functions, their arguments, timeout information etc.) and submits then to a Python [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) pool. I can provide the full (long) code  if requested, but the key step (as I see it) is the asynchronous application to the pool:

```
job.resultGetter = self.pool.apply_async(
    func = job.workFunction,
    kwds = job.workFunctionKeywordArguments
)
```

I am trying to use this parallel job processor with a large body of legacy code and, perhaps naturally, have run into [pickling](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) problems:

```
PicklingError: Can’t pickle <type ’instancemethod’>: attribute lookup builtin .instancemethod failed
```

This type of problem is observable when I try to submit a problematic object as an argument for a work function. The real problem is that this is legacy code and I am advised that I can make only very minor changes to it. So... is there some clever trick or simple modification I can make somewhere that could allow my parallel job processor code to cope with these traditionally unpicklable objects? I have total control over the parallel job processor code, so I am open to, say, wrapping every submitted function in another function. For the legacy code, I should be able to add the occasional small method to objects, but that's about it. Is there some clever approach to this type of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `dill` and `pathos.multiprocessing`  instead of `pickle` and `multiprocessing`.

see here:
[What can multiprocessing and dill do together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19984152/what-can-multiprocessing-and-dill-do-together)

http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2013/12/05/Parallelism-and-Serialization/

[How to pickle functions/classes defined in __main__ (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866944/how-to-pickle-functions-classes-defined-in-main-python/19428760#19428760)

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. Unhappily, I am limited in that ```multiprocessing``` is considered "validated" in the effort with which I am involved while more modern updates to it and similar parallel processing methods are not. However, I shall experiment. Thanks

Comment: Well, you could make a case for the fork of multiprocessing, as it's just an older version of multiprocessing with a hundred or two lines of that module's attempts at serialization pulled out and replaced with the one line "import dill".  Dill is primarily python's pickle with some additional serialization methods registered to the pickle registry.  However, it sounds like that won't help you have them considered "validated" -- does "validated" translate to "standard python library" or something like "EPD / Anaconda"?