# serialize / pickle a function that is defined in a string

Tags: python, serialization, namespaces, pickle, dill

I want to do the following:

```
import pickle
namespace = {}
exec('def f(x): return x', namespace)
pickle.dumps(namespace['f'])
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PicklingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-61493bb3c732> in <module>()
      2 namespace = {}
      3 exec('def f(x): return x', namespace)
----> 4 pickle.dumps(namespace['f'])

PicklingError: Can't pickle <function f at 0x7f2134171950>: it's not the same object as __main__.f
```

The problem that I want to solve: I have a function in string format and I need to be able to serialize it (for parallelization purposes.)

Comment: You should explain what is currently happening in your code that is not meeting expectation. What happens when that code runs right now. What do you expect should happen. What *exactly* are you trying to achieve with your code? Please revise how to put together a more solid [mcve] to help get your question across better.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have added the error message. Furthermore, I think that I describe my problem quite clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why use used the `dill` tag in your question, because you only used `pickle`... but if you really need your code to be exactly how you wrote it, with the one caveat that you can replace `pickle` with `dill`... it works:

```
>>> import dill as pickle
>>> namespace = {}
>>> exec('def f(x): return x', namespace)
>>> _f = pickle.dumps(namespace['f'])
>>> _f
'\x80\x02cdill.dill\n_create_function\nq\x00(cdill.dill\n_load_type\nq\x01U\x08CodeTypeq\x02\x85q\x03Rq\x04(K\x01K\x01K\x01KCU\x04|\x00\x00Sq\x05N\x85q\x06)U\x01xq\x07\x85q\x08U\x08<string>q\tU\x01fq\nK\x01U\x00q\x0b))tq\x0cRq\r}q\x0e(U\x0c__builtins__q\x0fc__builtin__\n__dict__\nh\nh\x00(h\rh\x0eh\nNN}q\x10tq\x11Rq\x12uh\nNNh\x10tq\x13R0h\x12.'
>>> f = pickle.loads(_f)
>>> f(5)
5
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just pass the current `global` namespace to exec, then you can pickle the function:

```
import pickle
exec('def f(x): return x', globals())
pickle.dumps(f)
```

Whether you can then load it in another environment, is an entirely different question as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866944/how-to-pickle-functions-classes-defined-in-main-python).

Answer (score 1):

Without using `globals()` the following works as well:

```
import pickle
namespace = {}
exec('def f(x): return x', namespace)
f = namespace['f'] # has to have the same name
pickle.dumps(f)
```

The function taken from `namespace` has to be defined in the function namespace under the same name.