# Get 'Can't get attribute" error while loading my pickel file

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to use pick to save and load my ML models but I get an error. Here is the simplify version of my code to save my model:

```
import pickle
def test(x,y):
    return x+y

filename = 'test.pkl'
pickle.dump(test, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

I can load the pickle file from the same notebook that I am creating it but if I close the notebook and try to load the pick in a new one with the below code:

```
import pickle
filename = 'test.pkl'
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))

It gets me this error:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 2
      1 filename = 'test.pkl'
----> 2 loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))

AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'test' on <module '__main__'>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an easy way to pickle a python function (or otherwise serialize its code)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253528/is-there-an-easy-way-to-pickle-a-python-function-or-otherwise-serialize-its-cod)

Comment: That post suggest using other packages which are not compatible with some of the Python ML libraries os I am looking for a solution to be able to use pickle

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866944/how-to-pickle-functions-classes-defined-in-main-python

Comment: So this link suggests evey time I want to load my script/model it will re-run the whole script. Then what is the advantage of pickling the model?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue as you. To fix this you need to import the function `test` in the file that you open the pickle file. In your example if the `test` function is located in the file `ml_model.py`, you need to add line   `from ml_model import test` in the second file.